# clientWidth and clientHeight always returns zero for ie7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I have no idea why, but clientWidth and clientHeight are always returning zero when I run this from IE in IE9 compat View, or IE7. It works for everything else.
Very simple code snippet with problem (so that you can try it too):
http://jsfiddle.net/nz2DA/

The code snippet found above is as follows...
I have a page containing the following HTML snippet:

```
<div id='aaa'>aaaaaa</div>​
```

And my javascript to test the clientWidth and clientHeight functions are as follows:

```
var el = $('#aaa')[0];
alert('Client width and height: '+ el.clientWidth + ' X ' + el.clientHeight);​
```

This always pops up an alert with "0 X 0" when I run in IE7 or IE9 Compatibility mode.

Any help or explanation would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So, I found a work around. I can just use the offsetWidth and offsetHeight to get these dimensions. I didn't post this as a solution because it isn't really a solution, but rather a work around.

Comment: Waiting for the $(document).ready(function(){....}) doesn't work either. I am also aware of the jquery functions for returning height and width, but I would like to know if there is a fix for these specific properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and following are the observations.

in IE(sucks!), if you didn't apply any styles for the "aaa" element IE won't calculate any width and height. So JS simply give you 0. But if you look at the box model from the IE dev tool bar you will see some value. So if you use `float:left` to that element JS will return a value, which is correct and all browsers will give you the same output.

Since you are using jQuery why don't you use `width()` or `outerWidth()` or `innerWidth()`. These methods are generelaized for the every browsers. Simply if you use `width()` you will see a very large width since you didn't apply any styles. In IE if element doesn't have an float value it gets it's parent width.In your case it's window width.

So if I modify your code to get correct width and height would be:

HTML:

```
<div id="aaa" style="float:left;">aaaaaa</div>
```

JS:

```
var el = $('#aaa')[0];
alert('Client width and height: '+ el.clientWidth + ' X ' + el.clientHeight);
```

Please let me know if you need more clarifications...
cheers!

Comment: Hi Roshan, Thanks for your observations. The issue I am having is to measure the div, not change its size. By adding the float:left the div changes its layout and size. I unfortunately don't have the luxury to change the layout. Thanks anyway! +1 for you

Comment: you said: "if you didn't apply any styles for the 'aaa' element IE won't calculate any width and height"... I guess this is the answer then. It can't be done! Aaargh! I will mark this as the answer until someone finds a workaround. If one exists!

Comment: as @Foz said, you can try out using `zoom:1` though I didn't checked it. Feel free to try it and let me now whether it's working or not...

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because of the "hasLayout" property in IE, and your div on its own does not "have layout". For more information, see http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Luckily you can trigger an element to have layout, which is why adding the "float:left" style works in the answer above. There are other triggers you can use too though that don't change the page. This one gives me proper values for clientWidth and clientHeight:

```
<div id="aaa" style="zoom: 1">aaaaaa</div>
```

The article says that setting "min-width: 0" should also work but it didn't for me. Setting "display: inline-block" worked OK but that might change your page. You can set these triggers in CSS so that the HTML doesn't need to change at all.

Comment: nice one! This works. See: http://jsfiddle.net/nz2DA/1/ Because @Roshan.Ind gave the answer first. I'll leave his as the answer, but +1 for you for giving the solution! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try **offsetHeight** property of internet explorer.